# Get CSS setting in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

Suppose I have a table in a web page:

```
<table><th id='th1'></th></table>
```

Then I define the CSS in the header:

```
#th1
{width: 100%;}
```

The question is, how to get the CSS width using JavaScript? I tried width, style.width, and jQuery("#th1").css("width"), but neither of them give me the result of '100%'.

Comment: I included the html for the table but it doesn't show up, it's just a simple table, with th tag, id='th1'...

Comment: @Estelle, when writing the post you can either surround code examples with the a backtick either side, or indent the code by four spaces; both will cause the code to be displayed/rendered as code. You can also select the text with your mouse/keyboard and then click on the button with the 1s and 0s on it to do the same.

Comment: thanks.
it's funny, I just want to say thanks but when I click Add Comment it tells me I need at least 15 characters -:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's no way to get the percentage value you specified in your CSS file for your element width.

A solution would be to calculate it like this :

HTML:

```
<h1 id="header">Hello, World</h1>
```

Javascript (jQuery):

```
var percentageWidth = (($("#header").width()*100)/$("#header").parent().width())+"px";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<h1 id="myHeader">Text</h1>

$('#myHeader').css('width');
```

Should work every time.

Comment: the problem is, in above sample, it returns px instead of 100%

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, if you want to get the actual current width in pixels, not what the CSS width says, you can do:

```
$('#th1').width();
```